# How do I get the name of a user from a BASE Google user object or from an email WITHOUT going through Admin SDK?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a Group object which is basically a mailing list for people within my Google Drive domain. This object contains a list of users of the class [base user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user.html)

This type of user object only allows me to get its email. With this email, or with the base user object, is there a way to find or access the [Drive user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user) object that has that email? The Drive user class does allow me to get the name of the user. Or, is there another way to get the name from that base user object?

I cannot use the Admin SDK because the organization I am working with will not allow me super-admin permissions (which I understand to be necessary to use the SDK). I know I have permissions to view the names of the users in the Group because if I share a document with those users I can then run code like this:

(modified from: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user)

```
// Log the names of all users who have edit access to a file.
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
var editors = file.getEditors();
for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(editors[i].getName());
}
```

I do get a list of their names. I could solve my problem this way, but it is a bit of a workaround and I would like something more direct like a getUserByEmail() method (if that existed) or a similar strategy.

Thanks

Comment: Hello @Trigaeten, are you able to view the names of the users of the group you are mentioning? From the group settings, NOT by sharing the documents. Cheers!

Comment: When I physically login to my Google Drive / Gmail, I can see the names of the people in the group. However, I am unable to access them programmatically as the Group object only gives me a list of base user objects that I can only call getEmail() on.

Comment: Hello @Trigaten, since the two object types are different and there's no way to associate any methods between the two, have you considered retrieving the users of the said group in a different way? Since I don't know exactly what are your permissions, I don't know what to suggest. Would you mind specifying which permissions you have for the said group/other G Suite apps that might be of help in retrieving the users names? Cheers!

Comment: I am not sure exactly what there permissions are called -- but I am working from essentially a normal account within the domain. I have an account which is part of the group and I have read-only access to the group. These are basically the same permissions I have everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getEmail() instead of getName().
From the Same document you mentioned.

Comment: I need to get the name of the user, not the email.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood. getName() was right approach. Maybe you want more shortcut.

Comment: It's not just that I want more shortcut -  I can't call getName() on the base user object, I can only call getEmail(). On the Drive user object, I can call getName(). However, the Group object gives me a list of base user objects.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you want cannot be achieved due to the fact that the retrieved objects are of different types.

So since the `User` class from the `Base` service only supports the `getEmail()` method, that is the only one you can use.

#### Reference

- [Base Service - User Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user.html)